OpenAlpr C# GuiTest Project "Error initializing OpenALPR"
I put the runtime_data dir and openalpr.conf.defaults in the gui's root project (not bin\Debug) and changes the last line of AssemblyDirectory to return Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Replace("/bin/Debug", "")); now, How do I config:
runtime_dir = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/openalpr/runtime_data

so that I don't get: "Error initializing OpenALPR"?
//Paths to runtime_data and openalpr.conf.defaults when debug:
C:\Users\..\Desktop\OpenAlprCS\AlprNetGuiTest\openalpr.conf.defaults
C:\Users\..\Desktop\OpenAlprCS\AlprNetGuiTest\runtime_data


